# ubuntu can not install software-properties-common

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get

I am trying to install `software-properties-common` and see following issue

```
root@e34e5a9927ea:/# apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates gir1.2-glib-2.0 iso-codes libdbus-glib-1-2 libgirepository-1.0-1 openssl python-apt-common python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi python3-software-properties unattended-upgrades
Suggested packages:
  isoquery python3-apt-dbg python-apt-doc python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg bsd-mailx mail-transport-agent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates gir1.2-glib-2.0 iso-codes libdbus-glib-1-2 libgirepository-1.0-1 openssl python-apt-common python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi python3-software-properties software-properties-common
  unattended-upgrades
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3556 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libdbus-glib-1-2 openssl ca-certificates libgirepository-1.0-1 gir1.2-glib-2.0 iso-codes python-apt-common python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi unattended-upgrades python3-software-properties
  software-properties-common
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libdbus-glib-1-2 amd64 0.100-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main openssl amd64 1.0.1c-3ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main ca-certificates all 20120623
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libgirepository-1.0-1 amd64 1.33.14-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main gir1.2-glib-2.0 amd64 1.33.14-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main iso-codes all 3.38-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main python-apt-common all 0.8.7ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main python3-apt amd64 0.8.7ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main python3-dbus amd64 1.1.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main python3-gi amd64 3.4.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main unattended-upgrades all 0.79.3ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main python3-software-properties all 0.92.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main software-properties-common all 0.92.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus-glib/libdbus-glib-1-2_0.100-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1c-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20120623_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gobject-introspection/libgirepository-1.0-1_1.33.14-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gobject-introspection/gir1.2-glib-2.0_1.33.14-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iso-codes/iso-codes_3.38-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt-common_0.8.7ubuntu4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python3-apt_0.8.7ubuntu4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus-python/python3-dbus_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygobject/python3-gi_3.4.0-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.79.3ubuntu4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python3-software-properties_0.92.9_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.92.9_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Do I need to do anything extra to make it work?

I am trying to learn docker and make image using [this](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/06/deploy-java-apps-with-docker-awesome/) reference

Answer (score 2):

Your image use ubuntu Quantal. Ubuntu Quantal is not supported anymore (http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)
You have multiple solution :

- Stay on Quantal, and change your apt-get source by adding the following lines in /etc/apt/sources.list

> ```
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe multiverse
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted universe multiverse
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted universe multiverse
> ```

- Or you can use an up to date image. Like ubuntu:14.04